# Duplicate Windows 10 desktop icons so that they're visible on all monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, icons, desktop, desktop-icons

I've recently got a second monitor for my PC. I'm running Windows 10 and I was wondering if there is a way to show the desktop icons that are on the main display on the other screen as well.

**Essentially both screen will have the same icons when showing the desktop.**

That way if I have a window in fullscreen on one monitor, if I wanted to access one of the desktop icons I could simply move the cursor to the next screen and click it instead of minimizing the current window.